# Question on the hitting probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am confused on the relation between some basic operations with sets and probability.

Consider a set 
$$
A=B\cup C\cup D
$$
with $B,C,D$ disjoint sets.

Take a random set $S$ almost surely non empty.

I have read in some sources that
$$
P(S\cap A\neq \emptyset)\leq P(S\cap B\neq \emptyset)+P(S\cap C\neq \emptyset)+P(S\cap D\neq \emptyset)
$$

Is there a way to write an exact expression for $P(S\cap A\neq \emptyset)$? E.g. 
$$
P(S\cap A\neq \emptyset)= P(S\cap B\neq \emptyset)+P(S\cap C\neq \emptyset)+P(S\cap D\neq \emptyset)+...?
$$

Comment: Yes, sorry, $S$ is a random set

Comment: Any book on theory on random sets. $P(S\cap A\neq \emptyset)$ is called containment functional.

Comment: Okay, ignore my comments.

Comment: Isn't $S\cap A=S\cap(B\dot{\cup}  C \dot{\cup} D)=(S\cap B)\dot{\cup}  (S\cap C)   \dot{\cup}(S\cap D)$?

Comment: well, it seems like if your random set is a singleton then the equality holds, otherwise you'll only have the sub-additivity